# SSL Certificate Dynamic DNS

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate

I own a domain at my DNS provider. I've pointed it to my house. My house keeps the IP address at the domain updated through dynamic DNS, so the A record always points to my IP address. I run OpenVPN at my house so I can connect from elsewhere. It's using a self-signed certificate. So, of course, I get SSL warnings when I connect.

My question is, Can I obtain an SSL certificate from StartSSL (free), set it up on OpenVPN, and get my browser to recognize the certificate as valid? For that matter, can I get any SSL certifcate to validate for any personal, development site I might set up at home in this situation? (OpenVPN.example.com, TestSite.example.com, etc)

(OpenVPN is not using port 443 or port 80, because I've heard that ISPs don't like it when you use those...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is Yes. When creating a SSL certificate request you set the "common name" to the DNS name of the host. You can change the type of DNS record (e.g. A, CNAME, etc.) or record value (e.g. 192.168.1.2) at anytime as long as the record name (e.g. vpn.example.com) is the same.

For a browser to recognize a SSL certificate (not give warnings upon connection) a matching Certificate Authority (CA) must ship (or be manually added) to your browser or OS. To avoid  SSL warnings with self-signed certificates you could instead provision a cert using a local/custom CA and install its root certificate on any necessary computers.

Comment: Indeed, what matters is that the name, as used by the client is matches the name in the cert. About the last sentence: by definition, a self-signed certificate is its own CA certificate. You were probably talking about using a local/custom CA.

Comment: @Bruno You are correct; I've updated my answer to be clear that you would need to use a local CA.